# SAFELY Installing Python 3.6 on Ubuntu with Python 3.8 already available

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, ubuntu, virtualenv

I am using [this package](http://pymeshsim.systemsgenetics.cn/tutorial.html), and one of its prerequisites is bcolz, which in turn [apparently] needs Pandas < 0.23. The Pandas version I have is 1.2, and I get this exception:

```
    BRs1 = self.convertToBroad(dui=dui1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyMeSHSim-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/pyMeSHSim/Sim/MeSHProcess.py", line 374, in convertToBroad
    return self._convertToBroadOrNarrowConceptID(dui=dui, rel="RB")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyMeSHSim-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/pyMeSHSim/Sim/MeSHProcess.py", line 348, in _convertToBroadOrNarrowConceptID
    df = self.getRelData(data="RNandRBRel")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pyMeSHSim-0.0.1-py3.8.egg/pyMeSHSim/data/dataInterface.py", line 99, in getRelData
    df1 = bz1.todataframe()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/bcolz/ctable.py", line 806, in todataframe
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(
AttributeError: type object 'DataFrame' has no attribute 'from_items'
```

I tried to downgrade Pandas from 1.2 to 0.22 by `python3 -m pip install pandas==0.22.0`, but I got an error again (a long long error I can't make much sense of).

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/install.html) for Pandas 0.22.0 says that it officially supports Python 3.6, Python 3.8, and Python 2.7, but I am quite worried about messing with Python on Ubuntu since my OS is doomed if I put a foot wrong. Does anyone know how I can safely install another Python version on Ubuntu? There's [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/682875/1132100) on askubuntu, but then it has strongly warned against changing the symlink, and I don't understand what exactly I should avoid doing. I did something similar once, and from then on I had to use `python3 -m pip` instead of `pip3` in order for Ubuntu to not confuse my two Python versions. Somebody suggested using synaptic on Ubuntu, but I wonder which of the following I should check here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6cTEH.png)

Another solution (that I think is more safe but needs more space) is using virtualenvs. I couldn't find any link that thoroughly explains working with them, except for perhaps [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), but I am new to it and as I said I need to be very careful. Does anyone know how good pyenv is, or what other solutions there are for maintaining more than one Python3 version on a single Ubuntu OS?

Comment: Get miniconda. Use conda to create environments specific to diferent projects.

Comment: I used pyenv and installed 3.6, now I have this problem: I can't install bcolz because of ``` error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 ``` .  They say I need to use ```  sudo apt-get install python3-dev ``` , but this Installs python3-dev for my other python version. It doesn't recognize ``` python3.6-dev ``` either, so I can't install it. Can one install apt-get packages specific for the python version inside the environment using miniconda? I mean I can install python packages for python3.6 using its pip, but I can't install apt-get packages for it.